# What "wmic bios get serialnumber" actually retrieves?

Tags: bios, wmic

I wonder what sort of serialnumber `wmic bios get serialnumber` Windows commad actually gives you?

Is it serial number of your motherboard? Documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the `wmic bios get serialnumber` command call the [`Win32_BIOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class and get the value of the  `SerialNumber` property, which retrieves the serial number of the BIOS Chip of your system.

Comment: And to further clarify, Win32_BIOS gets that information from the SMBIOS tables in the BIOS.  It is generally up to the system manufacturer to populate these tables with valid data.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS

Comment: Is it wise to use this as a unique machine-identifier?

Answer (score 2):

run `cmd`

Enter `wmic baseboard get product,version,serialnumber`

Press the enter key. The result you see under serial number column is your **motherboard** serial number

Answer (score 0):

Only AMD

```
ECHO
mkdir C:\SystemInfoAMD
systeminfo > c:\SystemInfoAMD\Informacion.txt

winget list > c:\SystemInfoAMD\Informacion\ListadoProgramas.txt

wmic LogicalDisk get Name,Size,FreeSpace > c:\SystemInfoAMD\InformacionDiscoDuro.txt

wmic baseboard get product,version,serialnumber > c:\SystemInfoAMD\SerialBios.txt
@echo off
```

Only INTEL

```
ECHO
mkdir C:\SystemInfoIntel 
systeminfo > c:\SystemInfoIntel\Informacion.txt

winget list > c:\SystemInfoIntel\ListadoProgramas.txt

wmic LogicalDisk get Name,Size,FreeSpace > c:\SystemInfoIntel\InformacionDiscoDuro.txt

wmic bios get serialnumber > c:\SystemInfoIntel\SerialBios.txt
@echo off
```

Answer (score -1):

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

if run from a command line (start-run should also do the trick) prints out on screen the Serial Number of the product,
(for example in a toshiba laptop it would print out the serial number of the laptop.
with this serial number you can then identify your laptop model if you need ,from the makers service website-usually..:):)

I had to do exactly that.:):)